# Meaning of “It is not intelligent, though it is the work of genius -- in the most nocturnal and Germanic sense of that bad word.”

Tags: phrase-meaning

The last sentence of Jorge Luis Borges’ review of “Citizen Kane” (in selected non-fictions) is:
*It is not intelligent, though it is the work of genius -- in the most nocturnal and Germanic sense of that bad word.*

I cannot figure out what Borges meant by *... genius -- in the most nocturnal and Germanic sense of that bad word.*

Comment: Litcrit may be OT.

Comment: Someone said: “Talent does what it can, genius does what it must.”  I take *genius* here to mean a compulsion (perhaps inflicted by a Muse) to make what the artist **must** make, before he is free to make what he would **like** to make.

Answer (score 1):

He is qualifying what he means by "genius." This is highly poetic, so I'm just taking a stab here, but if there is a specific context I am missing, please correct me...

Firstly, he is saying that he is using this word in an unconventional manner - he is not using the 'daily,' '9-to-5' definition of "genius," but rather a definition that you would bump into if you stayed up late (nocturnal.)

Secondly, he is making it clear that when he writes "genius," he doesn't mean 'super smart,' but rather, he means what the word historically (etymologically) meant, which was more like, as Webster defines, "attendant spirit [of a deity]." So it's more at that 'Citizen Kane is the product of a god working through a man...' I presume he says "bad word" because he is frustrated with how everyone just uses it to mean 'very smart,' these days.

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genius

Comment: Thank you tidbertum.
Your answer helped me to get the point about Germanic sense of the word “genius” but as for the use of “nocturnal” in the sentence I am not quite convinced.
If I’m not mistaken, the words genius, genie, and jinni are more or less synonymous. In some cultures it is believed that such (so-called) spirits are active only at night. Could Borges’ reference to “nocturnal” (nocturnal sense of the [bad word] “genius” be somehow related to this point?

Comment: excellent observation! that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

Borges loved to write in the realm of paradox or mashing together two ideas that ordinarily aren't used together. I think saying nocturnal he was referring to the aspect of dark genius or shadowy genius. The themes of Kane are both dark and shadowy, as is the cinematography. Germanic, I think, here means driven by the will, and not dark. Genius is considered a 'bad' word by Borges because it's thrown around so loosely. People would certainly call Borges a genius, but he considered himself a writer who tried to write something good and sometimes succeeded, maybe. So, he's very humble about his work and therefore the word genius is a loaded one to him. He says Kane is not intelligent but a work of genius - that's the kind of paradoxical pairing of ideas that Borges is very comfortable with.